# Process undergone before ApplicationStart method - .NET MVC Website

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web, application-start

When I click on the "Run" option in Visual Studio of my Web application, it builds all the projects, and my browser is opened.

It takes a minimum of 3 minutes for my browser window to open and to hit the breakpoint my ApplicationStart method in the global.asax file.

What are the process that is undergone before the ApplicationStart method? 
Can some one explain as I am new to .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't have enough information here to help you, is this a completely new project "from the box", nothing added to it? Tons of things can be the reason but we don't know anything about your project, elaborate on that please.

Comment: @Dimitri this is not a new project. its .NET website. i was asked to improve the performance of the initial loading of the website once the IIS is restarted. 

But in local, (release mode) , the application takes nearly 4-5 minutes to display the Home page of the website. Nearly 20 sub projects are loaded in the website.

Comment: Please update your original post with more information, we don't know what your project are doing so we can't possibly tell what is the cause neither what you could do to improve. You will have to include a lot more details, how many projects are there in total, show us some code where things are called from your Glabal.asax file to the page load of the first page and so on. A LOT MORE INFO is what we need here to help you :)